# Visual Basic Web Consumer w/Authentication

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, web-services

I am trying to create a Visual Basic Web Consumer solution in Visual Studio 2013.  The Web Service was written by another group in my company using Java and I have been successful in connecting to it using a Java CFXWebService client solution.  I was also successful in connecting to the Web Service using Visual Basic prior to the team adding authentication to the Web Service.  Since then I have been unable to get anything to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I a currently doing.

1. Created Windows client solution in Visual Studio
2. Added Web Reference to WSDL file
3. Added the following code to Windows client solution

   ```
   ' Create the web part service.
   Dim service As com.lenovo.plmrpttst.PartServiceService
   service = New com.lenovo.plmrpttst.PartServiceService

   ' Set credentials for web service
   Dim myCredentials As System.Net.CredentialCache = New System.Net.CredentialCache()
   Dim netCred As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
   myCredentials.Add(New Uri(service.Url), "Basic", netCred)
   service.Credentials = myCredentials


   'Declare result type
   Dim result As com.lenovo.plmrpttst.ptresultdata
   Try
       ' Get the result
       result = service.getPartBomService(PartNumber, Revision, Iteration)
   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.ToString)
   End Try`
   ```
4. Ran code and got the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toQSr.jpg)."Can't find the Header to validate user information!
   at
   Systen.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientProtocol.Invoke...

Any pointers on what to try next?